# nested trapz double integration

Tags: matlab, integral

I'd like knowing if there is any way to bypass the call for `quad2d` with a nested `trapz` loop. I'll discuss my problem with some more detail: currently, I perform the calculation of a double integral this way:

```
clc, clear all, close all
load E_integral.mat

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.0;

beta_int = (c*gamma)./(k_int.*sqrt(E_integral));

figure, loglog(k_int,beta_int,'r','LineWidth',2.0), grid on;

k1 = (.01:.1:100);
k2 = .01:.1:100;
k3 = -100:.1:100;

int_k3 = zeros(size(k2));
int_k3k2 = zeros(size(k1));

tic
for ii = 1:numel(k1)
    phi11 = @(k2,k3) PHI11(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_int,beta_int);
    int_k3(ii) = 2*quad2d(phi11,-100,100,-100,100);
end
toc
```

where `PHI11` is defined as

```
function phi11 = PHI11(k1,k2,k3,k_int,beta_int)
k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
ksq = k.^2;
k1sq = k1.^2;
fourpi = 4.*pi;
beta = exp(interp1(log(k_int),log(beta_int),log(k),'linear'));
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
k0sq = k0.^2;
k04sq = k0.^4;
Ek0 = (1.453.*k04sq)./((1 + k0sq).^(17/6));

C1 = (beta.*k1sq.*(k0sq - 2.*(k30.^2) + beta.*k1.*k30))./(ksq.*(k1.^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = ((k2.*k0sq)./((k1.^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2))).*atan2((beta.*k1.*sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2)),(k0sq - k30.*k1.*beta));
xhsi1 = C1 - (k2./k1).*C2;
xhsi1_sq = xhsi1.^2;
phi11 = (Ek0./(fourpi.*k04sq)).*(k0sq - k1sq - 2.*k1.*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1.^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_sq);
end
```

and `E_integral.mat` can be obtained this way:

```
clc,clear all,close all

k_int = .001:.01:1000;

Ek = (1.453.*k_int.^4)./((1 + k_int.^2).^(17/6));


E = @(k_int) (1.453.*k_int.^4)./((1 + k_int.^2).^(17/6));

E_integral = zeros(size(k_int));

for ii = 1:numel(k_int)    
    E_integral(ii) = integral(E,k_int(ii),Inf);    
end

save('E_integral','k_int','E_integral')
```

Now the question is: would it be possible to overlook `quad2d` and the `handle function` in favor of a more practicle approach, by using a nested `trapz` function?

So far, I've tried the following piece of code, which has not yielded to the expected results:

```
int_k33 = zeros(size(k2));
S_11 = zeros(size(k1));
tic
for ii = 1:1
    for jj = 1:numel(k2)
        int_k33(jj) = trapz(k3,PHI11(k1(ii),k2(jj),k3,k_int,beta_int));        
    end
    S_11(ii) = 4*trapz(k2,int_k33);
end
toc
```

Comment: Any interesting idea?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "practical approach"? I've only given this a precursory look and I can certainly see places to improve the code. That being said, generally speaking you can only break up a double integral `∫∫f(x,y)dA` into two separate integrals `∫g(x)dx * ∫h(y)dy` if you can write `f(x,y)` as the product of two functions `g(x)*h(y)`. Can you post the actual equations and their context? (factor of 1/(4pi) leads me to think something to do with magnetic fields.)

Comment: I *assume* you want to do this because you are given experimental data? Otherwise, it makes little sense to choose such a simple method over a more accurate one...Can you elaborate on *why* you want to do this?

Comment: And can you post the formulae for what you want to do? This question feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: And is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267784/calculate-a-double-integral) not the same?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: yes I need it for the second question and not for the `XY` one.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: basically I want to switch to this other procedure, because when I try matching `quad2d` results with some benchmark derived from a nsted `romberg integration` (which I assume quite close to a nested `trapezoidal`) on a journal, there quite a huge mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid using the `quad2d` function, but it's possible to split the 2D quadrature into two 1D nested quadratures (even if the function does not factorize).

Here is a way to process with the integration with two `trapz` calls. The point is to generate the set of all the values in a big table and the use `trapz` for both dimensions.

First, I define test values:

```
f= @(x,y) sin(x.*cos(y));
N = 1000;
```

Then, I define the grid for both the x and y directions (similar to your `k2` and `k3`):

```
xpts1d = linspace(0,1,N+1);
ypts1d = linspace(0,1,N+1);
```

I evaluate then the function f in all the pairs of points:

```
xpts = xpts1d'*ones(1,N+1);
ypts = ones(N+1,1)*ypts1d;
values = f(xpts,ypts);
```

Then, the integration can be done using two nested calls:

```
I = trapz(xpts1d,trapz(ypts1d,values,2),1);
```

This gives the correct answer.

---

In the first version of my answer, I had used the `quad` function, which works with function handles directly. The "naive" idea is to simply nest the two calls, like:

```
I = quad( @(y) quad( @(x)f(x,y) ,0,1),0,1)
```

but this does not work actually. The point is that the inner `quad` call does not work for vector valued functions while the outer call expects a vector values function.

To make it work, we simply need to change the inner call for the vector valued version of `quad`, `quadv`:

```
I = quad( @(y) quadv( @(x)f(x,y) ,0,1),0,1)
```

Now it should work and we can check that it actually gives the same answer as

```
I = quad2d( f, 0,1,0,1)
```

If you really want to use the `trapz` function, I suggest that you build a function on top of `trapz` that accepts a function handle and calls `trapz` inside.