# How to find integral under the noise power spectrum in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I have the 2D noise power spectrum (Matrix). How can I get integral under the noise spectrum in Matlab. Will the sum of the matrix element only give me integral?. I am doing to evaluate a correctness of noise power spectrum which said that the variance of image is equal to the integral under the noise power spectrum. I will appreciate your help. 
Thank you

Comment: For discrete-time signals, the integral is essentially the sum yes.  However, this is approximately equal to Riemann sums so it may not be as accurate as you want.  If you want to be more accurate, consider using the trapezoidal rule.  Here's a post on how it's done on 2D signals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405882/nested-trapz-double-integration

Comment: Thak you for your reply. My answer is close by just summing operation so didn't try with the trapezoidal rule but will try. Thank you again